# Using article with "regular basis"

Tags: grammar, articles, grammaticality, definite-article

Does `regular basis` needs an article before it?

> Use computers on regular basis

vs.

> Use computers on a regular basis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basis (meaning the way something happens, or is done or organized) is a singular noun and requires an indefinite article.

> I stroke my cat on a regular basis
>
> I call my mother on a daily basis.
>
> My uncle combs his hair on an irregular basis.
>
> Our skills need to be updated on an ongoing basis.